# file.Exist returns true on localhost and returns false on server c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, localhost, fileinfo

I've a grid that contains file list (that on another server) and download buttons for them on each row. When button clicked, file should be downloaded. When I click it on localhost, file.Exist returns true and I can download the file. However, when I try same button on server (IIS), file.Exist returns false and the file cannot be downloaded. (This server also can reach the file.) My code snippet is below;

```
            var fileNameToShow = "8D.xls";
            var fileNameAndPath = "\\\\10.1.101.151\\Files\\Live\\10\\8D.xls"
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileNameAndPath);
            file.Refresh();
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                // Send the file to the browser
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename= " + fileNameToShow + "; size=" + file.Length.ToString());
                Response.TransmitFile(fileNameAndPath);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("File does not exist!");
            }
```

What can I do to solve this?

> Edit:  File is in 10.1.101.151.  IIS is in another server.  My local
> is also another PC.

Comment: That simply means you forget to learn the key differences, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: You can access the file on localhost because the localhost is running with you credentials and has permission to read from the remote server.  On a IIS the server is not running with your credentials.  You have to setup the roles on the IIS to run with your credentials.  See : https://www.guru99.com/deploying-website-iis.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to set the permissions of the folder on the server, and add the server where the IIS is located to the server where the 8D.xls is located.
[image]

Second, you need to set the identity of the application pool, select a custom account, you can set the administrator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I edited the question. Could you please consider it again?

Comment: While I reproduced the issue and tested it, I put file on server1 and IIS on server2. I access the site on my local machine. The code I use in the application is the same as yours, the only difference is the file path, \\\\server IP\\c\\Files\\Live\\10\\8D.xls.  I store it in the C drive of the server1, so there's a C in the path.